# bash shell commands run through python to be universal with windows, mac, and linux

Tags: python, bash, docker

I need to have bash shell commands run through python in order to be universal with pc and mac/linux. `./bin/production` doesn't work in powershell and putting 'bash' in front would give an error that it doesn't recognize 'docker' command

./bin/production contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run --rm -it \
    --volume ${PWD}/prime:/app \
    $(docker build -q docker/prime) \
    npm run build
```

This is the python script:

```
import subprocess
from python_on_whales import docker
cmd = docker.run('docker run --rm -it --volume ${PWD}/prime:/app $(docker build -q docker/prime) npm run build')
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

This is the error I get when running the python script:

python_on_whales.exceptions.NoSuchImage: The docker command executed was `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.EXE image inspect docker run --rm -it --volume ${PWD}/prime:/app  $(docker build -q docker/prime) npm run build`.
It returned with code 1
The content of stdout is '[]
'
The content of stderr is 'Error response from daemon: no such image: docker run --rm -it --volume ${PWD}/prime:/app $(docker build -q docker/prime) npm run build: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
'

Running the command, `docker run --rm -it--volume ${PWD}/prime:/app $(docker build -q docker/prime) npm run build` in one long line in powershell works but we want a universal standard command for both pc and mac/linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python on Whales [`docker.run()`](https://gabrieldemarmiesse.github.io/python-on-whales/sub-commands/container/#run) function doesn't take a `docker run ...` command line.  It is a native Python API where you need to express the various Docker options as function parameters.

In principle you could rewrite this Python script using that API:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from python_on_whales import docker

# build the image, returns an Image object
image = docker.build(Path.cwd() / 'docker' / 'prime')

# start the container; like `docker run ...`
docker.run(image,
           command=['npm', 'run', 'build'],
           volumes=[(Path.cwd() / 'prime', '/app')], # -v $(PWD)/prime:/app
           interactive=True,                         # -i (required?)
           tty=True,                                 # -t (required?)
           remove=True)                              # --rm
```

The return value from `docker.run()` (without `detach=True`) is the container's stdout, and the examples `print()` that data.

Comment: (It seems like, when all is said and done, you've added two languages and a container system just to be able to run `npm run build` on your local source tree.  Might it be easier to install Node locally as part of your developer setup, and just run that one command when needed?)

Comment: This is what I get when I run that 'TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not iterable'

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option. We are required to run everything through docker

Comment: The `volumes` parameter needs to be a list; I've corrected that in the answer.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much! I am not too experience with python or docker so this was killing me.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you're looking for but you can always try this:

```
import platform
import subprocess
import os

cur_os = platform.system()

if cur_os == "Windows":
    print("You are on windows")
    os.system('Command here') # for windows
elif cur_os == "Darwin":
    print("You are on mac")
    subprocess.call('Command goes here') # for mac
```

Edit:
I'm intermediate with python so don't judge, if I did something wrong please give me feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Tried that and I get this error now: 
`
You are on windows
docker: invalid reference format.
`

Comment: Hmm, then idrk what's wrong with it.